# QML custom layout

Tags: qt, layout, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I am using QML to display a background image and this image needs to be overlaid by icons. Each of these items is attached a MouseArea so the icons are actually used as buttons.

Now the icons need to scale and move together with the background image. Their layout behavior need to be such that the icons look as if they were part of the background image (I did not include the icons into the background image because the icons are "active" and are associated the MouseArea).

The behavior I get is that the icons scale well with the background image (when the image is resized, the icons are rescaled accordingly) which is great. Now unfortunately the position x / y of the icons is not correct, I do not manage the find the formula for x /y such that the icons are moved together with the background resize and give the feeling that the icon are part of the background image.

Here is my current code:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Rectangle
{
    color: palette.grey

    // Manual move background and buttons.
    Image
    {
        id: robotBody
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 10
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height * 0.8
        source: "../UI/Pictures/ManualMove_body.png"
        smooth: true

        // Buttons.
        Image
        {
            id: xFrontButton
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            source: "../UI/Icons/ManualMove_XFront.png"
            smooth: true
            x: 0.8 * parent.paintedWidth
            y: 0.8 * parent.paintedHeight
            transformOrigin: Item.TopLeft
            width: implicitWidth * robotBody.paintedWidth / robotBody.implicitWidth
            // NOTE: no need to specify the height because of the preserve aspect ratio fill mode.

            MouseArea
            {
                id: xFrontMouseArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
                onPressed: { uiController.onXFrontMouseAreaPressed() }
                onReleased: { uiController.onXFrontMouseAreaReleased() }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Any idea of what is going wrong?

Thanks,

Antoine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget this moment:

```
x: (parent.width - parent.paintedWidth)/2 + 0.8 * parent.paintedWidth
y: (parent.height - parent.paintedHeight)/2 + 0.8 * parent.paintedHeight
```

I.e. do this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
//import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
//import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
//import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
//import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Rectangle
{
//    color: palette.grey
    color: "grey"

    // Manual move background and buttons.
    Image
    {
        id: robotBody
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 10
//        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height * 0.8
//        source: "../UI/Pictures/ManualMove_body.png"
        source: "Large.png"
        smooth: true

        // Buttons.
        Image
        {
            id: xFrontButton
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
//            source: "../UI/Icons/ManualMove_XFront.png"
            source: "small.png"
            smooth: true
            x: (parent.width - parent.paintedWidth)/2 + 0.8 * parent.paintedWidth
            y: (parent.height - parent.paintedHeight)/2 + 0.8 * parent.paintedHeight
//            transformOrigin: Item.TopLeft
            width: implicitWidth * robotBody.paintedWidth / robotBody.implicitWidth
            // NOTE: no need to specify the height because of the preserve aspect ratio fill mode.

            MouseArea
            {
                id: xFrontMouseArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
                onClicked: console.log("Heya!")
//                onPressed: { uiController.onXFrontMouseAreaPressed() }
//                onReleased: { uiController.onXFrontMouseAreaReleased() }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers from Russia :)

Comment: I added some custom images of my own to test, naming them Large and Small + disabled things, that were not necessary or unavailable with Qt 5.5 I have.

Comment: Hi mlvljr, you know what? You rock: it works all good! Now I am not sure I understand why this is needed: I would expect *(parent.width - parent.paintedWidth)/2* to be needed if the transformOrigin was the center of the Image, but I have actually changed this explicitely to *transformOrigin: Item.TopLeft*, just to avoid having to add this *(parent.width - parent.paintedWidth)/2*. It's fine if I have to add this code, it's just that I do not understand why I have to...

Comment: Thanks, reason is, you are not actually transforming anything here (i.e. no rotations or smth), just positioning items via good old x,y,w,h -- and then, all x and y values are from left and top and w and h stretch to the right and bottom -- and we have no other way to deal with this stick an image on top of another case other than to find the offsets of the parent image's visible portion from its left and top (and given the thing appears to be centered vertically and horizontally when aspect ratio is preserved -- we get where we are :)).

Comment: Shortly, transformations are a different beast, but the basic coordinate system is quite simple (and only has (0,0)s as origins).

Comment: Thanks mlvljr, this really helped!

Comment: @arennuit My pleasure, have fun with them robots :)